# Программа на Python работает некорректно

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
from flask import Flask 
from vsearch import search4letters
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def hello() -> str :
    return "Hello World from Flask!"
# Второй декоратор устанавливает URL 'search4'
app.route('/search4')
# Функция 'do_search' вызывает 'search4letters' и возвращает результат в виде строки
def do_search() -> str :
    return(search4letters('life, the universe, and everything', 'eiru!'))
if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Я запускаю код в командной строке и ввожу в поле поиска браузера 127.0.0.1:5000 на экране появляется первое сообщение "Hello World from Flask!", но когда ввожу 127.0.0.1:5000/search4 этот запрос, появляется сообщение 404.

Я занимаюсь с помощью книги <Изучаем программирование с помощью Python Head First>делаю точно также как в книге, но не получается. Создал свой модуль  установил этот модуль в папку где хранится вышеуказанная программа.

Comment: У вас нет второго декоратора.

Answer (score 1):

Собачку добавьте в этой строке

```
app.route('/search4')
```

Answer (score 1):

Строчку

```
app.route('/search4')
```

надо исправить на

```
@app.route('/search4')
```